# Using same port for IIS and Node JS

Tags: node.js, iis, socket.io, reverse-proxy

I have a web app built with PHP on IIS as backend and Node.JS socket.io for realtime communication, however I need to run both app (IIS and Node.JS) on a same port (443) to secure both connection, so im creating reverse proxy like this :

```
var httpProxy = require('http-proxy');
proxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer({}),
url = require('url');
http = require('http');

http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    var hostname = req.headers.host.split(":")[0];
    var pathname = url.parse(req.url).pathname;
    if(pathname == '/realtime_script')
            proxy.web(req, res, { target: 'http://localhost:8000/socket.io/socket.io.js' });
    else if(pathname.indexOf("/socket.io") > -1)
            proxy.web(req, res, { target: 'http://localhost:8000'+req.url });
    else
            proxy.web(req, res, { target: 'http://localhost:8080' });

}).listen(80, function() {
    console.log('proxy listening on port 9000');
});
```

I set socket.io to listen to port 8000 and IIS bind to port 8080, I managed to access home page using http://localhost, everything loads and connected perfectly (including socket.io), however every time a redirect happened (e.g submitting form or clicking a link), the node js crashed with this message :

```
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\node\node_modules\http-proxy\lib\http-proxy\index.js:119
throw err;
      ^Error: socket hang up
at createHangUpError (http.js:1472:15)
at Socket.socketCloseListener (http.js:1522:23)
at Socket.emit (events.js:95:17)
at TCP.close (net.js:465:12)
```

anybody can tell me what's wrong here?

Thank you

Comment: Why not do the reverse proxy with IIS? have node run on port 3000 or whatever and reverse from IIS to node.

Comment: Do you have any reference for that? (reverse proxy specifically for node) i'm totally clueless about IIS :(

Comment: Here's a step by step guide: http://blogs.iis.net/carlosag/setting-up-a-reverse-proxy-using-iis-url-rewrite-and-arr

Comment: do not use node as a reverse proxy. Use an actual reverse proxy, such as apache or nginx.